# CoreData - Modeling mapping table

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, iphonecoredatarecipes

Im planning on using CoreData to model a “News” iOS app. This’ll have many sections (read a UITabBarItem) which will contain many articles (in a UITableView). The articles might appear in other sections too. Also the **sort order** of each article is another important factor.

In database lingo I'd have

- "Article" table
- Sections" table and a
- "Article_Sections" table to map an article to a section with additional sort order field.

I have tried and can’t model this in CoreData. Im stuck with a

- “Section” class having a many-to-many relationship with
- a “Article” class (with an inverse many-to-many relationship to the “Section” class).

However with this I don’t know how to derive the sort order. Any hint on how to do this is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Sandeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to stop thinking in terms of database to sort this out. My solution involved 2 Classes:

- ArticleList

Properties:
         * List name
         * Article Id
         * Sort order

Relationship:
         * Article ; one-to-one

- Article

Properties:
         * Article Id
         * ....

Relationship:
         * List ; one-to-many

I query the ArticleList and sort on sortOrder to get a list of articles for a particular feed/section. Then use the valueForKeyPath: to fetch article properties (such as title etc).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to remove the direct relationship between section and article and just have a relationship from your Article_Sections table back to the section and article tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an entity "ArticleSectionPair" as an intermediary between "Section" and "Article" with:

- an attribute "sortValue"
- a one-to-many relationship "section" to the "Section" entity (with its reverse "articlePairs")
- a one-to-many relationship "article" to the "Article" entity (with its reverse "sectionPairs")

Using the attribute "sortValue" and th, you can get a sorted collection of ArticleSectionPairs from a section and get the articles with `[sortedArticlePairs valueForKeyPath:@"article"]`.